# How to write a verilog/system verilog of a normally open momentary switch toggle with delays

Tags: verilog

How to write in verilog and/or system verilog a normally open switch with delays with the following functionality: when pressed once it outputs 1 and stays 1 when depressed, when pressed a second time it outputs 0 and stays 0 when depressed. The 1 output is instantaneous upon pressing, the 0 output only occurs if the button is pressed for a determined time. This is essentially how the power button in desktops work: if computer is off pressing the button starts the computer but, if the computer is on, the button requires to be pressed for several seconds.

I am new to verilog; I would appreciate an actual verilog code of how to do this, including FSM if needed
Thanks a bunch
Cesar

Comment: Two state statemachine with a counter. (I assume there is a clock to count the off time delay.)

Comment: please try it yourself and present your results if you have issues.

Answer (score -1):

For any logic require a past value/state, it should consider a FSM. Write down all the state you need. And consider the relationship between output and different state.